# How to correctly use the Table.Repeat function?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm having some trouble getting the Table.Repeat function to work properly... I'm very new to PowerQuery/BI, so am just about getting my head wrapped around all the coding.

Following the syntax and it would appear everything is correct, given that the addition of columns is optional.

What I am aiming to achieve is to have the entire repeated a specific number of times, the repeat function described here sounds like it fits the bill. But when I have attempted to implement it, it results in an error.

I was previously using the Append Function, however, as I'm trying to append the query several thousand times, this results in the query crashing excel and has become uneditable after the initial setup.

I've tried implementing the Repeat code halfway through the query, where it's needed; and on a new sheet. Halfway through gave me an error stating: that it could not find a Value and that a table.

When I tired it on a new sheet, though I did not get an error, the applied sets disappeared and the data wasn't repeated. I tried the repeating tables, much lower I needed to test out,  but this still went into error.

```
#"Repeat" = Table.Repeat(#"8-1", 2)
```

Essentially the entire table repeated X number of times.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error you are getting and show the full context of where this code is? The function definitely does work, but maybe the name of the table you are trying to repeat is a typo or out of scope or something.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't at the Computer I was using.

Comment: ...    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Append - 1014" = Table.Repeat(#"Removed Blank Rows", 2),

Comment: So currently I've been testing this on the above code and another code (just as a test). No error is actually being prompted, what occurs is the applied steps disappear and the table does not actually repeat. Or not in anyway that i can see or how I'd imagine it...

Comment: You talk abou several thousand times... i see it only once. Please give full scope of problem in your question.

Comment: I'm just using one repeat as a practice... Which I can't achieve. I figured the problem was with the Syntax and I'd be able to simply change the number once that's achieved. P.S don't be confused by the "Append - 1014", this was from the previous instance.